# Postgres CDC not capturing data on Azure cloud

Tags: postgresql, cdc, streamsets

I installed StreamSets 3.8 and postgresql 10.12 on Azure cloud. It functions as expected except that the postgresql CDC is not capturing any changes of target monitoring table.

I have exactly same installation on local Ubuntu 18.04 LTS desktop, the CDC is working as expected.

I checked the replication slot of postgresql, it can output changes as expected. But in the postgresql CDC origin, there's no data incoming.

I am not sure it's the issue of the wal2json or postgresql CDC origin, and how to fix this issue.

Below is the wal2json installation and configuration steps:

https://github.com/streamsets/wal2json

Any thing I am missing here?

Comment: I'm guessing it is not possible to install the StreamSets wal2json on the Azure PostgreSQL instance?

Comment: I'm not so sure about that. I installed PostgreSQL by apt-get install postgresql-10, maybe should have nothing to do with Azure PostgreSQL instance?

Comment: Oh - I thought you might have been using one of the Azure-hosted versions.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [StreamSets documentation on the PostgreSQL CDC origin](https://streamsets.com/documentation/datacollector/latest/help/datacollector/UserGuide/Origins/PostgreSQL.html#concept_mj2_vgl_fhb), the currently supported versions of PostgreSQL are:

- PostgreSQL 9.4.18
- PostgreSQL 9.6.2
- PostgreSQL 9.6.9
- PostgreSQL 10.4

I'm guessing the problem is that PostgreSQL 10.12 isn't quite compatible. Not sure why it would be different between your laptop and Azure, though.